# How to send string or intger value from android studio App in Java to Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi, iot, java-websocket

I have managed to create a simple counter app in android studios. I would like to know if there is a possible way to send the integer value to raspberry pi from my android app. I am a beginner in coding and thus have difficulty understanding and implementing some of the solutions suggested online.

****The counter button was working last week, however, for some reason, it is not working now.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button buttonINC, buttonDEC;
    TextView tvDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonINC = findViewById(R.id.btn_inc_id);
        buttonDEC = findViewById(R.id.btn_dec_id);

        buttonINC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String currentvalue = tvDisplay.getText().toString();
                int value = Integer.parseInt(currentvalue);
                value++;
                tvDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(value));

            }
        });

        buttonDEC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String currentvalue = tvDisplay.getText().toString();
                int value = Integer.parseInt(currentvalue);
                value--;
                tvDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(value));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your buttons may work or nor work. But there is no code that sends something to a raspi. So what is your question?

Comment: Is it possible to send integer( 1,2,3.....) or strings ( UP or Down) from my android phone to raspberry pi. I am looking to control a robot through my android phone.

Comment: Of course that is possible.